# SQL developer suggests "missing right parenthesis". But I couldn't find where's wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

The code is as follows:

```
create table Person (
    personId        smallint  not null,
    title           char(5)   default null,
    personName      varchar2(50) not null,
    institution     varchar2(100),
    country         varchar2(30),
    phoneNo         varchar2(15),
    personEmail     varchar2(50),
    primary key     (personId),
    check (title in ('Mr', 'Ms', 'Miss', 'Dr', 'Prof',       null)),
    check ( length(phoneNo) between ( 8 and 15)),
    unique (personEmail));
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :) What exactly is the error? Do you have a message that you can paste to us or a screenshot?

Answer (score 5):

I think you have two issues.  Try this:

```
create table Person (
    personId        smallint  not null,
    title           char(5)   default null,
    personName      varchar2(50) not null,
    institution     varchar2(100),
    country         varchar2(30),
    phoneNo         varchar2(15),
    personEmail     varchar2(50),
    primary key     (personId),
    check (title in ('Mr', 'Ms', 'Miss', 'Dr', 'Prof') or title is null),
    check (length(phoneNo) between 8 and 15),
    unique (personEmail)
);
```

The syntax error is the parentheses around `(8 and 15)`.  I would recommend that the title be `varchar2()` rather than a fixed length string.

Another issue is the `NULL` in `in`.

What is the issue?  In most SQL expressions, `NULL` is treated as "false".  This is true of conditions in `WHERE` clauses and `CASE` expressions, for example.  `CHECK` constraints, for some reason, behave differently.  A `NULL` value passes the `CHECK` constraint.  I find all this confusing, so I prefer that my `CHECK` constraints evaluate to true or false.